# Is there a way to print the two text files one after the other inside jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have two text files:

First.txt

```
A1  B1  C1
A2  B1  C2
A3  B2  C2
A4  B3  C3
```

and

Second.txt

```
C1  D1
C2  D1
C3  D2
```

Here is the code written in jupyter notebook:

```
!type First.txt Second.txt
```

The output is given as:

```
A1  B1  C1
A2  B1  C2
A3  B2  C2
A4  B3  C3C1  D1
C2  D1
C3  D2
```

but I want the output to be like:

```
A1  B1  C1
A2  B1  C2
A3  B2  C2
A4  B3  C3
C1  D1
C2  D1
C3  D2
```

How can I print the two text files one after the other?

Answer (score 0):

I would not resort to shell commands for this. Just this snippet should work fine:

```
for filename in ["First.txt", "Second.txt"]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```